# Making a shader for a loaded OBJ model in Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have loaded a object(.obj) model using this (from this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/)):

```
void Model::loadOBJ(const char * path, std::vector < vector3 > & out_vertices,    std::vector < vector2 > & out_uvs, std::vector < vector3 > & out_normals){
std::vector<unsigned int> vertexIndices, uvIndices, normalIndices;
std::vector<vector3> temp_vertices;
std::vector<vector2> temp_uvs;
std::vector<vector3> temp_normals;

FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
if (file == NULL)
    return;
while (1){
    char lineHeader[128];
    int res = fscanf(file, "%s", lineHeader);
    if (res == EOF)
        break;
    if (strcmp(lineHeader, "v") == 0){
        vector3 vertex;
        fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
        temp_vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "vt") == 0){
        vector2 uv;
        fscanf(file, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y);
        temp_uvs.push_back(uv);
    }else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "f") == 0){
        std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
        unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
        int matches = fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);
        if (matches != 9){
            exit(matches);
            return;}
        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
        uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[0]);
        uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[1]);
        uvIndices.push_back(uvIndex[2]);
        normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
        normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
        normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
    }
}   
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i++){
    unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
    vector3 vertex = temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
    out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
}
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uvIndices.size(); i++){
    unsigned int uvIndex = uvIndices[i];
    vector2 uv = temp_uvs[uvIndex - 1];
    //vertex.normalise();
    out_uvs.push_back(uv);
}
}
```

And I draw it with

```
void Model::draw()
{   
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
for (int l_index = 0; l_index < vertices.size(); l_index++)
{
    glTexCoord2f(uvs[l_index].x, uvs[l_index].y);
    glVertex3f(vertices[l_index].x * 5, vertices[l_index].y * 5, vertices[l_index].z * 5);
}
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnd();
}
```

The model loads properly and saves the normal's, uvs, and the vertices from the .obj file.

How would I go about making a shader for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to read some tutorials on the basics of GLSL. Since your model contains xyz position, uv texture coordinates, and xyz normals, these will be your inputs to your vertex shader. The vertex shader will convert the vertices into clip space using your world/view/projection matrices, pass the texture coordinates to the pixel shader, and the pixel shader will look up the color from the texture map.